# fpclassify(): what are the examples of another implementation-defined categories?

Tags: c, floating-point

N2479 C17..C2x working draft — February 5, 2020 ISO/IEC 9899:202x (E) (emphasis added):

> The fpclassify macro classifies its argument value as NaN, infinite, normal, subnormal, zero, or into *another implementation-defined category*.

Question: what are (at least some of) the examples of *another implementation-defined categories*? Any experience with them?

Comment: That actually seems odd. [`fpclassify(3)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fpclassify.3.html) has nothing discussed any other impl.-defined category, neither anything relevant's written in `math.h` function definition.

Comment: Given "Additional implementation-defined floating-point classifications, with macro definitions beginning with FP_ and an uppercase letter, may also be specified by the implementation." does not require _mutually exclusive_ kinds of floating-point values_, I could see a category of _canonical_, the preferred encoding.

Comment: @chux: C 2018 7.12 6 specifies the *number classification macros* and says they are mutually exclusive. So additional ones should exclude the base ones.

Comment: As a point of reference, IEEE 754-2008 5.7.2 defines a `class` operation that indicates one of ten classes: signaling NaN, quiet NaN, −∞, −normal, −subnormal, −0, +0, +subnormal, +normal, and +∞. But `fpclassify` cannot distinguish these without violating the mutual exclusivity requirement noted in my comment above, unless the draft C standard removes that requirement.

Comment: @EricPostpischil As I read it, "FP_INFINITE FP_NAN FP_NORMAL FP_SUBNORMAL FP_ZERO represent the mutually exclusive kinds of floating-point values. They expand to integer constant expressions with distinct values.".  The spec is silent on the exclusiveness of additional categories.  The "they" refers to the prior set.

Comment: @EricPostpischil OTOH "or into another implementation-defined category." does support the idea that another implementation-defined category would be exclusive to the first 5.

Comment: Double extended format as defined for Intel x86 gives rise to a number of operand classes that don't fall into the standard `fpclassify` classification scheme, caused by explicit integer bit of significand. If stored exponent is zero, but significand is non-zero with the integer bit set, this is a pseudo-denormal (treated as equivalent normal). If the stored exponent is maximum, but integer bit of significand is clear, it is a pseudo-NaN or pseudo-Infinity (-> invalid op. exception). Any other exponent value combined with zero integer bit in significand is an unnormal (-> invalid op exception)

Comment: Here is a fairly recent [discussion](https://sourceware.org/pipermail/libc-alpha/2020-November/119949.html) how the GNU toolchain should handle the "special" x86 double-extended operands that don't fall neatly into the ISO defined `FP_*` categories